# How to find the count/number of paragraphs in the table (having merged cell)?

Tags: c#, .net

How to find the count/number of paragraphs in the table (having merged cell)? 
How can I get the current paragraph number in the word document.

Below is my code  where I am splitting the cell based on the paragraphs. but the  final value is not matching with the correct paragraph value.

```
for (int k = 1; k < range.Cells.Count; k++)
 {
    if (range.Cells[k].Range.Text.TrimEnd(exclusions).ToString() != "")
    {
       String[] temp = range.Cells[k].Range.Text.Split('\r');
       int tempcnt = temp.Length - 1;
       j = j + tempcnt;
    }
 }
```

Comment: plz post some data of document and code too

Comment: I have one word document where I am reading the document paragraph by paragraph, I want the current paragraph number to assign some conditions in the code. 
The above code is for reading the table (having merged cell) I just want to know how many paragraph are there in that table or need the paragraph number of the next line after this table. so i can continue my reading part of document.